# Multi-thread downloading with FileDownloader

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to use [`lingochamp/FileDownloader`](https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader) to download files from an Android application. It is currently working fine (downloading on a single thread mode), but I cannot figure out how to use their multi-thread downloading feature. As I read on an issue it has been implemented in the class [`DownloadLaunchRunnable`](https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/liulishuo/filedownloader/download/DownloadLaunchRunnable.java). I tried creating this class and calling its `run` method, but nothing is happening. Their documentation is pretty short and does not include this part, the multi-thread downloading is not included in their demo app either. Can someone with more experience in Android developing try to figure how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Just create and start a thread:

```
custListLoadThread = new Thread(loadRunnable);
custListLoadThread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Used ThreadPoolExecutor for MultiThread executor.
Might be helpful this link please check it for more details [Executor Framework](http://codetheory.in/android-java-executor-framework/) and [ThreadPoolExecutor Android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)